# Conditionally format cell if value entered already appears in same row, next column which is CSV

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, gs-conditional-formatting

I'm want to conditionally format A3:A if the value entered in A3:A already appears in B3:B, which contains CSV,  >1 time.

(A3:A will be CONCATENATED to B3:B, so the value will automatically appear at least once.)

Basically, if the value is not already present, there will be no formatting and I know to go ahead and add (leave it).  If it *is* present, format the cell to alert me not to add (or delete).  There may be numerous values in some cells and not so easy to glance to see if the value in question is already present.

I attempted to use `REGEXMATCH`, but not really sure how to switch the `TRUE` to a numeric value.
`=IF(LEN(A3),REGEXMATCH(B3,A3),)`

I've also found other formulas using `COUNTIF` and `COUNTA` that perform a similar action, but none that consider CSV.

[My sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10idK7L5VMfxokho4KNiN-YxZlxhrKXtk9oH9a5DR8fQ/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

custom formula for CF:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXMATCH(A3,TEXTJOIN("|",1,TRANSPOSE(QUERY(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(TRIM(
 SPLIT(B3,","))), "select Col1,count(Col1) group by Col1"), 
 "select Col1 where Col2 > 1", 0)))))
```

[image: 0]